# Makefile implicit rule matching - prefix length not affecting match

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, gnu, rule

In my gnu-make-3.81 Makefile, I wish to define two implicit rules, such that the more specific first one takes precedence over the more general second one:

```
src/%_bar.o : src/%_bar.c
    $(CC) -Wall -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -c $^ -o $@

src/%.o : src/%.c
    $(CC) -Wall -c $^ -o $@
```

The issue I have is that foo_bar.c represents autogenerated code that triggers a warning with -Wall that I'd prefer to suppress, so the first rule is meant to catch this special case.

According to [make's manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Match.html):

> It is possible that more than one pattern rule will meet these criteria. In that case, make will choose the rule with the shortest stem (that is, the pattern that matches most specifically).

I thought that for a filename of `src/foo_bar.o`, the first rule would generate the stem `foo`, and the second would generate `foo_bar`. The former is the shortest so I'd expect it to apply. However this doesn't seem to be the case, the second rule is selected by make and executed. Running `make -d` doesn't even show an attempt to match with the stem `foo` - only `foo_bar` is considered.

If I make the following change, by making the second rule's stem deliberately longer by shortening the prefix from `src/` to `sr`, the second rule is still selected:

```
src/%_bar.o : src/%_bar.c
    $(CC) -Wall -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -c $^ -o $@

sr%.o : sr%.c
    $(CC) -Wall -c $^ -o $@
```

I can't reconcile this with the make documentation.

In addition, if I remove the `src/` prefix entirely, the second rule *is* selected:

```
src/%_bar.o : src/%_bar.c
    $(CC) -Wall -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -c $^ -o $@

%.o : %.c
    $(CC) -Wall -c $^ -o $@
```

Although this solves my problem, it's actually not suitable because it overrides/interacts with another implicit rule on the current directory that I need to keep:

```
%.o : %.c
    # do something else
```

My question is why does `make` behave this way in this case, and is this consistent with the documentation? If so, is there a better way to specify a more specialised implicit rule?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, be aware that the "shortest stem" method of pattern matching was introduced in GNU make 3.82.  If you're using GNU make 3.81 then your version of make uses the old method which was "first match".  It's always best to read the documentation that comes with your distribution, if possible, rather than the web documentation because the web documentation is for the latest version of GNU make.  GNU make 3.81 was released in April 2006... that's pretty old.

However, the example you provided actually DOES work the way you wanted it to:

```
src/%_bar.o : src/%_bar.c ; @echo shorter: $*

src/%.o : src/%.c ; @echo longer: $*

all: src/foo_bar.o

$ make-3.81
shorter: foo

$ make-3.82
shorter: foo
```

I suspect that when you asked your question here you didn't use the same code you're using in your real environment.  In that environment you must have the shorter pattern *after* the longer pattern, like this:

```
src/%.o : src/%.c ; @echo longer: $*

src/%_bar.o : src/%_bar.c ; @echo shorter: $*

all: src/foo_bar.o

$ make-3.81
longer: foo_bar

$ make-3.82
shorter: foo
```

When asking questions it's very important to be sure that the simplified examples in the question accurately reflect the real situation.

Comment: Thank you - I hadn't realised there was a mismatch between make versions. I had wrongly assumed my recent Linux distro was using the same version as the docs. With this in mind, this does make sense now, as my other implicit rule was preceding these special cases, so it was being picked up first. I take your point about making sure examples reflect reality - in this case I'd oversimplified.